# MS Project get Taskdependencies property via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project, excel-import

I am currently creating a macro in Excel VBA to import data from a MS project document.

I included all properties that I want to import in my code but couldn't find the correct for TaskDependencies (i, 15). This property should include "True" if a Predeccessors OR Successors is true - "False" if both are false.

I receive a Runtime Error '438'
Object does not support this property or method

Is it maybe the wrong property? Can somebody help me out here?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task - here are all properties be found afaik.

Thanks in advance

Best regards
CKay

```
Sub ImportDataFromProject()
    Dim objProject As Object 'MS Project application
    Dim objTask As Object 'Task object
    Dim strFileName As String 'File name
    Dim i As Long 'Counter
    Dim fd As FileDialog 'File dialog object

    'Create file dialog object and set properties
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.Title = "Wï¿½hlen Sie eine Project-Datei aus"
    fd.Filters.Clear
    fd.Filters.Add "Project-Dateien", "*.mpp"

    'Show file dialog and get file name
    If fd.Show = -1 Then 'User clicked OK
        strFileName = fd.SelectedItems(1) 'Get first selected item

        'Create MS Project instance and open file
        Set objProject = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
        objProject.FileOpen strFileName

        'Loop through tasks and copy data to Excel
        i = 4
        For Each objTask In objProject.ActiveProject.Tasks
            If Not objTask Is Nothing Then 'Skip blank rows
                Cells(i, 1) = objTask.ID
                Cells(i, 2) = objTask.Name 'Copy task name to column A
                Cells(i, 3) = objTask.Start 'Startdatum
                Cells(i, 4) = objTask.Finish 'Enddatum
                Cells(i, 5) = objTask.Predecessors 'Vorgï¿½nger
                Cells(i, 6) = objTask.Successors 'Nachfolger
                Cells(i, 7) = objTask.Summary ' Sammelvorgang
                Cells(i, 8) = objTask.Milestone 'Meilenstein
                Cells(i, 9) = objTask.Duration 'Dauer
                Cells(i, 10) = objTask.PercentComplete 'Fertigstellung
                Cells(i, 11) = objTask.ConstraintType 'Einschrï¿½nkungstyp
                Cells(i, 12) = objTask.Active 'Aktive Aktivitï¿½ten
                Cells(i, 13) = objTask.FreeSlack 'Freie Puffer
                'Cells(i, 14) = objTask.X
                Cells(i, 15) = objTask.TaskDependencies 'Verknüpfungen
                Cells(i, 16) = objTask.Critical ' Kritisch
                Cells(i, 17) = objTask.ConstraintDate 'Einschrï¿½nkungstermin
                
                i = i + 1 'Increment counter
            End If
        Next objTask

        'Close MS Project file and application
        objProject.FileClose False
        objProject.Quit pjDoNotSave

    Else 'User clicked Cancel or closed the dialog

        MsgBox "Keine Datei ausgewï¿½hlt."

    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: CKay, TaskDependencies is a collection, it is not a true or false property. You are already capturing the Predecessors and Successors fields so I'm not sure why you want to use TaskDependencies at all

Comment: Try: Cells(i, 15) = (objTask.TaskDependencies.Count > 0)

Comment: John-project you are right, I just wanted to have it all in the macro-code. Guess I will do a Incell formula and ask for Predecessors and Successors.

@RachelHettinger didn't work sadly, got another runtime error. Tried also with just Predecessors or Successors >0 ----> this compiled but received just "True" in all cases, which is wrong.

Comment: Ckay, sorry I'm lost as to exactly what you want to appear in Cells(i,15). Are you after a count of task dependencies? If not a count, what then?

Comment: No problem. In Cells(i,15) should appear a boolean if that task has a dependency. Since .TaskDependencies didn't work, I tried the suggestion from Rachel but the results were not what I wanted. Therefore I decided to make an if-statement in the cells directly:

If(or(E4>0;F4>0);TRUE)

This is the only field were I can do something on my own and dont have to pull it from the project, so this will be fine.

Thanks all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Half of an answer, more of a way around:**

Since TaskDependencies is the only field which can be filled without pulling it from the project, I decided to create a If-Statement directly in the cells to create a way around:

```
If(or(E4>0;F4>0);TRUE)
```

E= predecessors F= Successors 4= where my list starts

Since "[TaskDependencies gets a collection of dependent (predecessor and successor) tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.taskdependencies)", this solution is viable for me.
Not the cleanest, but it'll do.